# Laravel multitenancy routes

Tags: routes, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I have a Laravel [multitenancy](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/routes/) working apllication. I need to add one route. So I did it, then run php artisan route:clear and cache:clear. Then I run php artisan route:list but I do not see new route in the list. I can see all routes around but not the new one. May be the problem is realted to Docker cause application is in docker container.
This is the router:

```
Route::get('/tenants', [TenantsController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/tenants/list', [TenantsController::class, 'list']);  // New one
Route::get('/tenants/{id}', [TenantsController::class, 'show'])->where('id', '\w+');
Route::post('/tenants', [TenantsController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('/tenants/{id}', [TenantsController::class, 'update'])->where('id', '\w+');
Route::delete('/tenants/{id}', [TenantsController::class, 'destroy'])->where('id', '\w+');
Route::delete('/tenants', [TenantsController::class, 'destroyAll']);
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't `/tenants/list` be handled by `/tenants/{id}` already? Does it show up when you use `/tenant/{id}` instead?

Comment: Yes application try to handle it by show method. But the problem is in docker. routes were not added in volumes.